# Get content with libxml2

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

I'm trying to use libxml2's function xmlNodeGetContent to acess content from an xml file, but for some reason content within self-closing tabs can't be read.

```
void parseRow (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *key;
    cur = cur-> xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"row"))) {
            key = xmlNodeGetContent( cur->children );
            printf("keyword: %s\n", (char*)key);
            xmlFree(key);
        }
        cur = cur -> next;
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm using this sample xml file with both types of tabs and the first row tab can be read while the second one returns (null);

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<story>
  <storyinfo>
    <author>John Fleck</author>
    <datewritten>June 2, 2002</datewritten>
    <row> Id="1" UserId="1" </row>
    <row Id="1" UserId="1" />
    <keyword>Id="hello"</keyword>
  </storyinfo>
</story>
```

Comment: I think you mean "tag" not "tab" and "empty" not "self closing". Actually, you're referring to elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second row element is empty, it has no content, only attributes.

```
<tag>non-empty content</tag>
<tag content="attribute value"/>
```

Without any schema, it's impossible for the framework to know what type the second tag element is and it can't have a default value defined for it, and it can't derive a type, therefore it has no content.  It does have a content attribute however, but you access attributes using different methods in most of the frameworks I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the attribute value, use xmlGetProp.